# Non well formed numeric value formed when using array_splice

Tags: php, arrays, pagination, array-splice

I am using array_slice in PHP like so:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && !isset($no_pagination)) {
        $page_num = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
        $limit_value_from = $page_num * 10;
        $limit_value_to = $limit_value_from + 10;
        $limit_query = $limit_value_from.", ".$limit_value_to;
    }

if (!isset($no_pagination) && isset($limit_query)) {
        $usernames_new = array_splice($usernames, $limit_query);
        $usernames = $usernames_new;
    }
```

When I run the script it gives me this error: A non well formed numeric value encountered. When I echo the $limit_query string it gives me the correct 0, 10 10, 20 20, 30 values, and if I manually enter 0, 10 10, 20 etc. into the function it works fine. Why is this error happening even though it is properly formatted?

Note: When I place the @ symbol before the array splice line the code works fine... Just wanted to know why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look to be passing the wrong arguments for that method.  The second argument is an INT.

```
array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )
```

Try this:

```
$usernames_new = array_splice($usernames, $limit_value_from, $limit_value_to);
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! Still looks to me like my code should work... But in any event, your changes made it work without errors, so that's always best :)

Comment: very important that you cast the second parameter to an integer. e.g. (int)$second_parameter